# Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'SQLite.SQLite_Bridging'

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite

I recently added SQLite to my project through cocoapods. I getting these errors:[image]

I'm using Xcode 10.1 and swift 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a [closed issue](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/856) about this.

Try with the [commit](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/commit/cf4183f4ef54c5c9e82176cc46451934c8fdec2a) that fix it and see if the problem is fixed. You can update your `Podfile` with this:

`pod 'SQLite.swift', :git => 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift', :commit => 'cf4183f4ef54c5c9e82176cc46451934c8fdec2a'`